# How the Scanner class Handles input

Tags: java

I am facing a problem with .nextInt() leaving off \n in the input
when I call .nextLine() after .nextInt(), the .nextLine() does not read a String from me because it consumes the \n left off by the .nextInt()

```java
public class Employee
{

    private String name;
    private int ID;

    public Employee (int ID, String name)
    {
       this.name = name;
       this.ID = ID;
    }

}
```

the main method is

```
System.out.println("Enter the ID number followed by the First and Last Name of the Employee");
Employee E1 = new Employee (input.nextInt(), input.nextLine());
```

The first parameter in the object E1 accepts input, for example 5000
but the second parameter does not accept anything because it reads the \n left by the input 5000\n left off by the .nextInt()

I have two methods I can do to over come this problem, but I want to see what the professional developers would do.

1. in the constructor, switch the places of the parameters (int ID, String name) to (String name, int ID) and then in the main method you would have

   ```
   Employee E1 = new Employee (input.nextLine(), input.nextInt());
   ```
2. Define variables in the main method called String name and int ID

   ```
   int ID = input.nextInt();
   input.nextLine();           // this consumes the \n left off by the input.nextInt()
   String name = input.nextLine(); 
   Employee E1 = new Employee (ID, name);
   ```

How would you solve this problem?

Comment: #2 seems reasonable and appropriate.

Comment: @Progman Thank you for your reply, No it does not answer my question as I have used that in my method #2. My question is essentially 
I want to put the Scanner in the argument for the constructor of Employee in the following shape:

Employee E1 = new Employee (input.nextInt(), input.nextLine());

Comment: You could also create your own class that wraps Scanner and provides an API suited to your needs. But you need to consider what happens if the user enters "ABC" for the integer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Integer.parseInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) method if you are certain the user input will be an integer.

```
System.out.println("Enter the ID number followed by the First and Last Name of the Employee");
Employee E1 = new Employee(Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine()), input.nextLine());
```

But you will get a `NumberFormatException` if the input can not be parsed to be an integer.

Comment: Even with `input.nextInt()` the results won't be very nice if the user doesn't actually enter an integer.

Comment: Agreed. Most probably the author of the question is not concerned about input validation.

Answer (score 0):

`"I have two methods I can do to over come this problem, but I want to see what the professional developers would do."`

Now, I'm no *professional developer* (just a hobby) but this is how I would do it. I personally wouldn't use the **Scanner#nextInt()** method or any other `.nextFoo()` method for that matter, except for **Scanner#nextLine()**. I would use `.nextLine()` for everything. For example, below is a runnable which is basically the same concept except with User Input Validation (read the comments in code):

```
public class EmployeeEntryDemo {

    // OS dependent newline character sequence:
    final String ls = System.lineSeparator();
        
    // Declare a Scanner object and Open a keyboard input stream:
    final java.util.Scanner userInput = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        
    // List Interface of Employee to hold instaces of Employee:
    java.util.List<Employee> employeeList = new java.util.ArrayList<>();

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* App started this way to avoid the need 
           for statics (unless we want them):  */
        new EmployeeEntryDemo().startApp(args);
    }
    
    private void startApp(String[] args) {
        String id;              // A string variable to temp hold Employee ID:
        String name;            // A string variable to temp hold Employee Name:
        int employeeCount = 0;  // An integer variable to keep count of employees entered.
        // Inform requirements:
        System.out.println("Supply any number of Employees:" + ls
                         + "-------------------------------" + ls);
        
        // OUTER LOOP:
        boolean quit = false;  // Flag for outer `while` loop condition
        while (!quit) {
            employeeCount++;
            // PROMPT #1:
            // GET EMPLOYEE ID FROM USER (as many times as desired):
            id = "";        // Used for inner `while` loop condition:
            // Keep looping while id is empty (Null String (""))
            while (id.isEmpty()) {
                // Prompt:
                System.out.println("Enter the employee #" + employeeCount 
                                  + " unique ID number or,");
                System.out.print("enter 'A' to auto-generate ('D' when done): -> ");
                // Get User input and trim off leading/trailing white-spaces (if any):
                id = userInput.nextLine().trim(); 
                
                // Has 'd' for `Done` been entered?
                if (id.equalsIgnoreCase("d")) {
                    // Yes...set the `quit` flag to boolean true;
                    quit = true;
                    employeeCount--;  // Remove 1 from employeeCount:
                    break;  // Break out of this inner loop:
                }
                // Otherwise, has 'a' for auto=generate ID been entered?
                else if (id.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {
                    // Yes... Is the employeeList empty?
                    if (employeeList.isEmpty()) {
                        // Yes...Then we can start IDs at 1
                        id = "1";
                    }
                    // No...employeeList is not empty...
                    else {
                        // Generate a unique ID value...
                        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
                        // Add 1 to the highest ID value in the employeeList List:
                        for (Employee emp : employeeList) {
                            if (emp.ID > max) {
                                max = emp.ID;
                            }
                        }
                        id = String.valueOf((max + 1)); 
                    }
                }
                /* No...Hopefully, just an ID value was supplied. Validate the fact:
                   Is the supplied string the representation of an unsigned integer 
                   value and, is it unique (not already used within the `employeeList`
                   List)?                */
                if (!id.matches("\\d+") || !isID_Unique(employeeList, Integer.parseInt(id))) {
                    /* No...Inform the User of an invalid entry and allow to try again.
                       If the ID number supplied is an string integer but is not unique
                       (has been used previously) then inform as well within the same 
                       message. Ternary Operator is used for this:                */
                    System.out.println("Invalid ID (" + id + ") Entry! " + 
                                (id.matches("\\d+") ? "ID is already in use! " : "") 
                                + "Try Again..." + ls);
                    id = "";  // Empty `id` to ensure re-loop:
                }
            }
            // End Of Prompt #1 Inner Loop:
            // If we made it to this point in code, then the ID is valid!
            
            // Was the `quit` flag set to boolean true from inner loop?
            if (quit) {
                // Yes..Then break out of this Outer loop:
                break;
            }
            
            // Display the determined unique ID number:
            System.out.println("Unique ID: " + id + ls);

            // PROMPT #2:
            // GET EMPLOYEE NAME FROM USER:
            name = "";        // Used for 2nd inner `while` loop condition:
            // Keep looping while name is empty (Null String (""))
            while (name.isEmpty()) {
                // Prompt:
                System.out.print("Enter the employee #" + employeeCount + " name: -> ");
                
                // Get User input and trim off leading/trailing white-spaces (if any):
                name = userInput.nextLine().trim();
                
                /* If no name was supplied or the name contains numerical digits
                   then inform the User of an Invalid Name Entry and allow to try 
                   again:  */
                if (name.isEmpty() || name.replaceAll("\\D", "").length() > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid Name (" + name + ") Entry! The name "
                            + "must contain something and can not contain digits!");
                    name = "";  // Empty `name` to ensure re-loop:
                }
            }
            // End Of Prompt #2 Inner Loop:
            // If we made it to this point in code, then the Name is valid!

            // Create and add the Employee instance to the `employeeList` List:
            employeeList.add(new Employee(Integer.parseInt(id), name));
            
            System.out.println();   // Add a blank line for Prompt aesthetics.
        }
        // End Of Outer Loop

        /* Display any collected instances of Employee within the 
           Console Window in a table type format (See the Employee
           class `toTableString()` method):           */
        if (!employeeList.isEmpty()) {
            // Display a Title:
            String displayTitle = "Employees List (" + employeeCount + " employees):";
            // String#join() is used below but if Java11+ then you can use String#repaeat():
            String displayTitleUL = String.join("", java.util.Collections.nCopies(displayTitle.length(), "="));
            System.out.println(ls + displayTitle + ls + displayTitleUL + ls);
            
            // Display the header and table data:
            for (int i = 0; i < employeeList.size(); i++) {
                // Ternary Operator is used here:
                System.out.println(
                        (i == 0 ? employeeList.get(i).toTableString(true) 
                                : employeeList.get(i).toTableString())
                        );
            }
        }
        
        // Indicate Quiting:
        System.out.println(ls + "Quiting - Bye Bye" + ls);
    }
    
    /**
     * A Helper Method to check if the supplied ID number is unique. This means 
     * that the supplied ID number does not already exist within the `employeeList` 
     * List.<br><br>
     * 
     * @param list ( {@code List<Employee> })<br>
     * 
     * @param id (int) The Integer ID value to check for uniqueness.<br>
     * 
     * @return (boolean) Boolean true if the supplied Integer is deemed to be 
     * unique and boolean false if it is not unique.
     */
    public static boolean isID_Unique(java.util.List<Employee> list, int id) {
        boolean result = true;
        if (!list.isEmpty()) { 
            for (Employee emp : list) {
                if (emp.ID == id) {
                    result = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    
    // INNER CLASS: (should be a .java class file on its own - here as demo only):
    public class Employee {
        
        // Class member (instance) variables:
        int ID;
        String name;

        // Constructor:
        public Employee(int ID, String name) {
            this.ID = ID;
            this.name = name;
        }

        /**
         * A Table style toString() method.<br><br>
         * 
         * @param applyHeader (Optional - Boolean VarArg) Default is false. If 
         * nothing is supplied, then default false will be implied and no header 
         * will be returned with the table data. If boolean true is supplied, 
         * then a an underlined header string will be applied the the returned
         * table data.<br>
         * 
         * @return (String) Employee class member variables data in a table
         * style string format:
         */
        public String toTableString(Boolean... applyHeader) {
            /* A boolean flag to indicate whether or not a 
               header should also be returned. Default false 
               which means - NO                */
            boolean addHeader = false; 
            if (applyHeader.length > 0) {
                addHeader = applyHeader[0];
            }
            String ls = System.lineSeparator();
            String header = String.format("%-12s %-15s%n", "ID", "Employee Name");
            // String#join() is used below but if Java11+ then you can use String#repaeat():
            String underline = String.join("", java.util.Collections.nCopies(header.length(), "-")) + ls;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
            
            if (addHeader) {
                sb.append(header).append(underline);
            }
            sb.append(String.format("%-12d %-15s", ID, name));
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
        
}
```